# Why is this Zend Framework _redirect() call failing?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

I am developing a Facebook app in Zend Framework. In startAction() I am getting the following error:

The URL http://apps.facebook.com/rails_across_europe/turn/move-trains-auto is not valid.

I have included the code for startAction() below. I have also included the code for moveTrainsAutoAction (these are all TurnController actions) I can't find anything wrong with my _redirect() in startAction(). I am using the same redirect in other actions and they execute flawlessly. Would you please review my code and let me know if you find a problem? I appreciate it! Thanks.

```
  public function startAction() {
    require_once 'Train.php';
    $trainModel = new Train();

    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

    require_once 'Zend/Session/Namespace.php';
    $userNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('User');
    $trainData = $trainModel->getTrain($userNamespace->gamePlayerId);

    switch($trainData['type']) {
      case 'STANDARD':
      default:
        $unitMovement = $config->train->standard->unit_movement;
        break;
      case 'FAST FREIGHT':
        $unitMovement = $config->train->fast_freight->unit_movement;
        break;
      case 'SUPER FREIGHT':
        $unitMovement = $config->train->superfreight->unit_movement;
        break;
      case 'HEAVY FREIGHT':
        $unitMovement = $config->train->heavy_freight->unit_movement;
        break;
    }
    $trainRow = array('track_units_remaining' => $unitMovement);
    $where = $trainModel->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $trainData['id']);
    $trainModel->update($trainRow, $where);
    $this->_redirect($config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/move-trains-auto');
  }
.
.
.
  public function moveTrainsAutoAction() {
$log = Zend_Registry::get('log');
$log->debug('moveTrainsAutoAction');
    require_once 'Train.php';
    $trainModel = new Train();

    $userNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('User');
    $gameNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Game');

    $trainData = $trainModel->getTrain($userNamespace->gamePlayerId);

    $trainRow = $this->_helper->moveTrain($trainData['dest_city_id']);
    if(count($trainRow) > 0) {
      if($trainRow['status'] == 'ARRIVED') {
        // Pass id for last city user selected so we can return user to previous map scroll postion
        $this->_redirect($config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/unload-cargo?city_id='.$gameNamespace->endTrackCity);
      } else if($trainRow['track_units_remaining'] > 0) {
        $this->_redirect($config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/move-trains-auto');
      } else { /* Turn has ended */
        $this->_redirect($config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/end');
      }
    }
    $this->_redirect($config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/move-trains-auto-error'); //-set-destination-error');
  }
```

Comment: Not 100% - and as such not going to write this as an answer =) - but have you tried converting %5F's into underlines, since that's what they represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer. It appears that Facebook does not play nice with redirect, so it is neccessary to use Facebook's 'fb:redirect' FBML. This appears to work:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/move-trains-auto"/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@Jani Hartikainen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448694#comments-1448694) points out in his comment, there is really no need to URL-encode underscores. Try to redirect with literal underscores and see if that works, since I believe redirect makes some url encoding of its own.

---

Not really related to your question, but in my opinion you should refactor your code a bit to get rid of the switch-case statements (or at least localize them to a single point):

controllers/TrainController.php

```
[...]
public function startAction() {
    require_once 'Train.php';
    $trainTable = new DbTable_Train();

    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

    require_once 'Zend/Session/Namespace.php';
    $userNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('User');
    $train = $trainTable->getTrain($userNamespace->gamePlayerId);

    // Add additional operations in your getTrain-method to create subclasses
    // for the train
    $trainTable->trackStart($train);
    $this->_redirect(
       $config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/move-trains-auto'
    );
  }
  [...]
```

models/dbTable/Train.php

```
  class DbTable_Train extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
  {
     protected $_tableName = 'Train';
     [...]
     /**
      *
      *
      * @return Train|false The train of $playerId, or false if the player
      * does not yet have a train
      */
     public function getTrain($playerId)
     {
         // Fetch train row
         $row = [..];
         return $this->trainFromDbRow($row);

     }
     private function trainFromDbRow(Zend_Db_Table_Row $row)
     {
         $data = $row->toArray();
         $trainType = 'Train_Standard';
         switch($row->type) {
           case 'FAST FREIGHT':
             $trainType = 'Train_Freight_Fast';
             break;
           case 'SUPER FREIGHT':
             $trainType = 'Train_Freight_Super';
             break;
           case 'HEAVY FREIGHT':
             $trainType = 'Train_Freight_Heavy';
             break;
         }
         return new $trainType($data);
     }

     public function trackStart(Train $train)
     {
         // Since we have subclasses here, polymorphism will ensure that we 
         // get the correct speed etc without having to worry about the different
         // types of trains.
         $trainRow = array('track_units_remaining' => $train->getSpeed());
         $where = $trainModel->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $train->getId());
         $this->update($trainRow, $where);
     }
     [...]
```

/models/Train.php

```
abstract class Train
{

   public function __construct(array $data)
   {
      $this->setValues($data);
   }

   /**
    * Sets multiple values on the model by calling the
    * corresponding setter instead of setting the fields
    * directly. This allows validation logic etc
    * to be contained in the setter-methods.
    */
   public function setValues(array $data)
   {
      foreach($data as $field => $value)
      {
         $methodName = 'set' . ucfirst($field);
         if(method_exists($methodName, $this))
         {
            $this->$methodName($value);
         }
      }
   }
   /**
    * Get the id of the train. The id uniquely
    * identifies the train.
    * @return int
    */
   public final function getId () 
   {
      return $this->id;
   }
   /**
    * @return int The speed of the train / turn
    */
   public abstract function getSpeed ();
   [..] //More common methods for trains
}
```

/models/Train/Standard.php

```
class Train_Standard extends Train
{
    public function getSpeed ()
    {
       return 3;
    }
    [...]
}
```

/models/Train/Freight/Super.php

```
class Train_Freight_Super extends Train
{
    public function getSpeed ()
    {
       return 1;
    }

    public function getCapacity ()
    {
       return A_VALUE_MUCH_LARGER_THAN_STANDARD;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I agree: that code does require refactoring. It's ugly and unmanageable. The data should be moved from application.ini to a db table. Your suggested code is very impressive, but possibly a bit overkill for such a simple application :)  Thanks for going to all that effort though!

Answer (score 0):

By default, this will send an **HTTP 302 Redirect**. Since it is writing headers, if any output is written to the HTTP output, the program will stop sending headers. Try looking at the requests and response inside [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

In other case, try using non default options to the *_redirect()* method. For example, you can try:

```
$ropts = { 'exit' => true, 'prependBase' => false };
$this->_redirect($config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/move-trains-auto', $ropts);
```

There is another interesting option for the *_redirect()* method, the *code* option, you can send for example a **HTTP 301 Moved Permanently** code.

```
$ropts = { 'exit' => true, 'prependBase' => false, 'code' => 301 };
$this->_redirect($config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/turn/move-trains-auto', $ropts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Daniel. I tried them, but the error remains. Still, I appreciate the help.